# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error when I get data from a textbox

Tags: asp.net, exception, datetime

```
       // ddlDepartureTime is a dropdown list
 string hourtime = ddlDepartureTime.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //String format exception occurs here ? 
            // txtDepartureTime is a text box 
            DateTime departuretime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDepartureTime.Text.ToString() + " " + hourtime, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Could you guys suggest the way to edit for me. Thanks a lot.

I updated follow Jakob's suggestion, but it still doesn't work.

```
 // ddlDepartureTime is a dropdown list



DateTime hourtime = DateTime.Parse(ddlDepartureTime.SelectedItem.ToString());
                //String format exception occurs here ? 
                // txtDepartureTime is a text box 
                DateTime departuretime = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDepartureTime.Text.ToString() + " " + hourtime, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Edit: My last solution is that I don't use DateTime anymore. Because this is just my school project. I moved to use String and it worked fine :).

Comment: A few tips for improving your chance of a response: 1) Tag your question with the programming language in question. 2) Include the actual exception message in your question, so we know what error you're getting - preferably with a stracktrace. 3) Shorten your title - "Please check for me a little of code." is needless. And 4) In your case examples of the actual value from the dropdown list would help.

Comment: You do a `ParseExact` with a specified format of just a date, but you appear to supply date + time. Would a format of "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" work? What is the exact value that goes into ParseExact (`txtDepartureTime.Text` and `hourtime`)?

Comment: As Hans says, you are parsing a string which has a time attached to it, `hourtime`, so it will not match the format `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. What is the value of `txtDepartureTime` and `hourtime` in this example?

Comment: I am going to take  the value of txtDepartureTime from a Textbox and hourtime from a dropdownlist. I want to add an image but I do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the question. which type of input are you taking in text box and what exactly you want as the results.
Are you taking complete date in text box?
Is the text box attached with some calendar control. your question donot gives the proper details

Comment: The value of txtDepartureTime from a Textbox and hourtime from a Dropdownlist and I just want to add in to database.

Comment: anothershrybery has also asked for the same thing.what i am asking is what will you take in txtdeparture...for e.g it would be minutes , complete time, complete date time, time with hours , minutes and seconds. what will be the input exactly

Comment: Sr for my late response. The value of txtDeparture is date with format 23/05/2012 and plus the value of hourtime which look like 6:30AM.